# Which roswtf plugins can be installed and how?

Tags: ros, roswtf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Which `roswtf` plugins can I install? How can I install `roswtf` plugins? (I just found [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/Getting%20started%20with%20roswtf) for [roswtf](http://wiki.ros.org/roswtf) which did not address the installation of plugins.)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273143/which-roswtf-plugins-can-be-installed-and-how?/) by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 468 on 2017-10-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't say for certain, but I doubt there are any plugins for `roswtf` other than the one in `tf`.

Six reasons for that:

1. the [wiki/roswtf](http://wiki.ros.org/roswtf) page shows only two *Used by* entries: that list is based on the info in the package manifest, and plugins typically have a `run_depend` and / or `build_depend` on the package that they are providing plugins for. In this case that list only contains `tf` and `ros_comm`. `ros_comm` is `roswtf`'s metapackage, so doesn't count. That leaves `tf`, which does indeed have an [export line for a roswtf plugin](https://github.com/ros/geometry/blob/c8358c9c446106272b05f87adeae0ca2c83b6a36/tf/package.xml#L52).
2. the [wiki/roswtf/Plugins](http://wiki.ros.org/roswtf/Plugins) page states that the plugin API is "*very experimental*", which doesn't invite people to contribute / write plugins.
3. a Google search ([this one](https://www.google.nl/search?q=%22roswtf+plugin%22+package.xml)) for `"roswtf plugin" package.xml` does not return any real results for me other than wiki mirrors, the above mentioned API wiki page, package manifest specs and similar pages. And of course the `package.xml` of `tf`.
4. A Github search ([this one](https://github.com/search?l=XML&q=roswtf+plugin&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93)) doesn't return anything other than the `package.xml` of various cloned/forked/copied `tf` packages.
5. `rospack plugins --attrib=plugin roswtf` returns only `tf` on a system with 'all' ROS packages installed (`apt install ros-$distro-*`).
6. I've never seen any other than the `tf` one (weak, I know).

Note that 1 is actually not 'exhaustive', as the *used by* list can only show pkgs the ROS buildfarm knows about. It could well be that users/companies/organisations have written `roswtf` plugins that were never/aren't released.

But I would've expected the Google search to show some results in that case.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-16**:
I realise I didn't address your "how would I install them" sub question, but seeing as there aren't really any, it didn't seem important.

But in short: just like any other ROS package: either build them from sources, or use `apt` to install the released `.deb`.